# Funcion dentro de funcion anonima JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Realizo una practica y tengo una duda, se instancia la función Subasta y se envía juan como parámetro a la función registrar, funciona perfecto de esta manera, regresando la función en `return`

```
const Subasta = function(){
    let compradores = {};

    return {
        registrar: function(usuario){
            compradores[usuario.nombre] = usuario;
            usuario.sala = this;
        }
    }}


const subasta = new Subasta();
subasta.registrar(juan);
```

Pero si escribo la funcion sin `return` de la siguiente manera, no funciona y me dice que nunca se lee la función, quisiera saber el motivo por el cual se tiene que hacer con un `return` y no normalmente
de la siguiente manera

```
const Subasta = function(){
    let compradores = {};


        function registrar(usuario){
            compradores[usuario.nombre] = usuario;
            usuario.sala = this;
        }
    }}

const subasta = new Subasta();
subasta.registrar(juan);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haber entendido bien su pregunta. Lo que sucede es normal por el comportamiento de JavaScript. Se está utilizando la función padre como un objeto, en JavaScript, hay diferentes formas de hacer un objeto, pero la manera en la que lo haces, no permite acceder a los métodos que están dentro.

Es decir, para el primer caso, puedes acceder al método porque, gracias al `return`, este se comporta como una "**propiedad**" de tu *objeto* a la cual puedes *acceder y ejecutar* como lo hiciste.

Básicamente el `return` hace lo siguiente:

```
const Subasta1 = function() {
        let compradores = {};
        // Cambio return por this.registrar
        this.registrar = function(usuario) {
                // Mis instrucciones
                return 'Funciona 1';
            }
    }
```

En cambio, para el segundo caso, no podrías acceder porque no tiene ese comportamiento. Si quieras acceder de todas maneras, tendrías que utilizar el **prototype** y añadir tus métodos mediante ello:

```
const Subasta2 = function() {
        let compradores = {};

        // Mis instrucciones
    }

    // Forma de agregar método
    Subasta2.prototype.registrar = function(usuario) {
        return 'Funciona 2';
    };
```

Y en ambos casos puedes acceder de la misma manera:

```
const subasta1 = new Subasta1();
const subasta2 = new Subasta2();
console.log(subasta1.registrar('1')); // Funciona 1
console.log(subasta2.registrar('2')); // Funciona 2
```

Answer (score 0):

básicamente lo que hace el `return` es finalizar la ejecución de la función y especificar un valor para ser devuelto a quien llama a la función. Si esto la función no tendría un valor que devolver. Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente es por el **scope**(alcance) en JS.

En el primer caso puedes notar que al dar un **return** estas diciendo que el objeto contiene una propiedad que retorna una funcion.

En el segundo caso estás declarando la función sin embargo esta no está disponible fuera de tu objeto, sino unicamente internamente. Para que esta cunfione puedes agregarla como propiedad:

```
const Subasta = function(){
    let compradores = {};


    let registrar = function(usuario){
            compradores[usuario.nombre] = usuario;
            usuario.sala = this;
        }
    }}

const subasta = new Subasta();
subasta.registrar(juan);
```

Para mas información de scope acá te dejo un [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-scope-in-javascript-cbd957022652/)